# In RXJS, is there a way to omit the res and err calls on .subscribe()?

Tags: rxjs

Given an observable where you subscribe:

```
Observable.subscribe(
  (res) => {},
  (err) => {},
  () => {
    // do some thing on complete
  }
);
```

Is it a requirement to write (res) and (err)?

Reason being, I'm using `Observable.forkJoin([Observable1, Observable2]).subscribe`, and I only care about when they are done, and maybe if they yield an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To omit the next and error functions, pass `undefined` for those parameters:

```js
Rx.Observable
  .from([0, 1, 2])
  .subscribe(
    undefined,
    undefined,
    () => console.log("completed")
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would opt to use the `.finally()` operator instead of omitting the `res` and `err` callbacks. This to better convey what it is that you want to happen.

```
Rx.Observable.forkJoin([obs1, obs2])
  .finally(() => console.log('done'))
  .subscribe();
```

Note that it is not required to pass the callbacks to `subscribe()`.

Comment: The `finally` operator will see the callback invoked if the observable terminates with an error, too - so it's not quite the same as leaving out the error handler. But it does look nicer.

Answer (score 1):

If we are talking of RxJS5 at least, you can also define the specific subscriber methods you want.

```
Observable.subscribe(
  (res) => {},
  (err) => {},
  () => {
    // do some thing on complete
  }
);
```

becomes

```
Observable.subscribe(
  complete: () => {
    // do some thing on complete
  }
);
```

As a side note, the other methods that can be explicitly defined are **next** and **error**.

Comment: I'm using `rxjs: 5.0.0-beta.12`, I'm not able to do this without the lint throwing me an error telling me a comma is expected where the colon is. What TypeScript version do you need?

Comment: I just tried again with the environment I have here, with typescript 2.1.5 and RxJS 5.0.3, using literally:

data$.subscribe({ complete() { console.info('done'); }});